# MySQL : GROUP_CONCAT the column and its count

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm having a `customer_status` table where the column "id" is unique and `cust_id` is customer id
and "status" is the current status of the customer.

The table is as follows:

```
id       cust_id       status
1          1            NEW
2          2            NEW
3          1            VIEWED
4          1            NEW
5          1            VIEWED
6          1            NEW
```

Now my requirement is to show the status and the status count for each customer.

For example consider cust_id = 1 then output should be:

```
NEW : 3
VIEWED : 2
```

I tried using group_concat but couldnot succeed with displaying status and status count, seperated with colon.

Please help me out.

Comment: `group_concat()` is not appropriate for this, unless you want the results as a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CONCAT:

```
select CONCAT(status,':',count(status)) from customer_status as result where cust_id = 1 group by status;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get what you want without group_concat:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM customer_status WHERE cust_id = 1 GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select count(status),status from customer_status where cust_id=1 group by status
```